# Turn on/off Sound

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I would like to turn the sound on and off by clicking on the button.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     buttonSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundan);
     CommonMethod.soundplayer.stop();

     //buttonSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundaus);
     //CommonMethod.soundplayer.setVolume(0,0);
 }
```

This is the CommonMethod

```
public class CommonMethod {

    public static MediaPlayer soundplayer;
    public static void Soundplayer(Context ctx,int raw_id)
    {
        soundplayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,raw_id);
        soundplayer.setLooping(true);
        soundplayer.setVolume(100, 100);
    }
}
```

It stops the sound by clicking but it doesn't turn it on again

I got this Code too, but its the same problem

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                    buttonSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundan);
                    CommonMethod.soundplayer.setVolume(100,100);

                }
                else
                {
                    buttonSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundaus);
                    CommonMethod.soundplayer.setVolume(0,0);

                }

            }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Also, this is not an Eclipse issue.

Comment: if i turn off the sound it cant turn on again

Comment: soundaus or soundan check

Comment: soundaus=soundoff /soundan = soundon thats german

Comment: There are some better ways to code this. To make your life easier, figure out a flag or something to keep from having to comment out one thing and rebuild the app each time. _But_ to keep from having a major no-no in your app, *do not* keep a static reference to a MediaPlayer, which in turn keeps a static reference to your context and is a memory leak nightmare.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have `public static MediaPlayer soundPlayer`, which is a static MediaPlayer. The problem with that is the MediaPlayer is instantiated with a context, `soundplayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,raw_id);`. That means it has a reference to the context. If you keep static reference to something that references a context, you are keeping a static reference to your context, which is a memory leak issue. Instead, the MediaPlayer will need to be managed in a local, non-static way.

Comment: i've found a solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please see this piece of [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

There are some useful ballots like:

> A MediaPlayer object must first enter the Prepared state before
>   playback can be started.

or

> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare()
>   or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the
>   Prepared state again.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pause` it instead of `stooping` if you stop then you have `prepaid` it again then it will `play` rather then you can `pause` and play`` again from same position.

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mPlayer.pause();
} else {
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

understand the below diagram.

[image]